# Enumerate and apply WPF styles programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard, styling

I have a WPF button as such

```
<Button Name="HelloWorldButton"
        Width="100"
        Height="100"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Style="{StaticResource TileButton}">
    Hello world
</Button>
```

Using WPF styling I have applied a style template as shown below

```
<Style x:Key="TileButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="focusRect"
                        Margin="-6"
                        BorderThickness="6">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="focusRectBrush" Color="Transparent" />
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="focusRectBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                    To="Red" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="focusRectBrush"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                    To="White" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I would now like to apply the MouseOver `VisualState` programmatically. I have looked through the `HelloWorldButton.Style` property and cannot see any obvious way of achieving this.

**Note:** Obviously I understand that it would be trivial to programmatically add a border to the button directly without using the declared XAML style sheet, however in my scenario this is not a viable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally worked it out.

The code I was looking for was as simple as

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(HelloWorldButton, "MouseOver", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
<Button Name="HelloWorldButton"
    Width="100"
    Height="100"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Style="{StaticResource TileButton}" MouseEnter="HelloWorldButton_MouseEnter">
```

I then duplicated another style "Tilebutton2" style where I change the color red to green, and in the MouseEnter event I put in:

```
 HelloWorldButton.Style = this.Resources["TileButton2"] as Style;
```

Now when you mouse over the button the border is now green.

Comment: Much appreciate the input but I think you might have completely missed the point of my requirements. The above example still requires that the code behind is directly dependent (and makes references to) the resources of the button. If I could use such an approach, I would just add the border directly.